# What is the word for the dead skin on the upper layer of a healed wound?

Tags: dermatology, terminology

I aggressively cleaned my ear canal with my finger and the canal got scratched. After several weeks elapsed, it got naturally healed but I cannot hear clearly probably because of the dead skin left inside. I want to remove it but I am in Japan right now, so I need to find the correct English word first to be translated to Japanese.

Is there any word to convey the same meaning as the dead skin I described above? Medical terminology is preferred.

Comment: Like a scab? Or scar tissue?

Comment: @mfoy_: Hmmm.. scab sounds appropriate.  :-)

Comment: A scab isn't dead skin. Hang on, there's a better site...

Comment: Health professionals tend to hang out on Health.SE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Frankly, medical terminology isn't necessary and might even lead to increased confusion, especially after being translated. All medical terminology is *not* universal.

Just state your complaint in plain language as clearly as you can using layman's terms. I doubt that a Japanese doctor needs much more guidance from you than simply understanding your complaint. For example, you might say (in Japanese), "Doctor, I can't hear as well as I used to and I think it may be due to an injury to my ear canal some time ago. Can you please have a look?"

I would expect the doctor to examine both ear canals. If your theory is correct, the doctor won't need further explanation. She will see it with her own eyes and know what to do about it. She will probably also want to test your hearing in both ears. I would not be terribly surprised to find that the cause is something other than what you suspect.

Assuming that you don't speak fluent Japanese and he/she doesn't speak fluent English, you might consider bringing a translator along with you since the doctor will no doubt have questions and perhaps need to explain things to you. It's the sort of situation where language barriers can be troublesome and you don't want to risk misunderstandings.

Comment: +1 for a great answer and especially *she [the doctor]*. It's great to see gender neutrality on the web!